# C: value vs type vs expression

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Let's say I want to build a C compiler in some OO language, so I create classes like `Scope`, `Object`, `LValue`, `Type`, `Pointer`, `Expression`, etc.

What I need to understand is what is the exact relationship between types, values, expressions and objects. Because some C references say something like:

> Expression *evaluates* to lvalue.

In other places you can read something like:

> lvalue *is* an expression...

So, how exactly do the C concepts relate to each other?

For binary expression, say addition `a + b`, the `a` and `b` operands, are those *expressions*? Or *objects*? Or just *types* that may or may not be an *object*?

Consider a simple code:

```
int a = 1;
a++;
```

- `a++;` is *expression-statement*, right?
- `a++` is *expression*, with postfix increment operator, right?
- `a`, so what is `a`? Is it *expression*, *object*, or *lvalue*? Or is `a` an *expression* that evaluates to *lvalue* and this *lvalue* has an associated *object* and *type*?

---

**EDIT**: What I am doing is writing a library (called `jsc`) that will allow to "write C in JavaScript".

Consider the following C function:

```
void main() {
    int a = 100;
    int b = 200;
    int c = 300;
    return a + (b + c);
}
```

Using `jsc` *builder* interface in JavaScript you would write that function like so:

```
var _ = require('jsc').Builder.context();

var main = _.func(_ => {
    var a = _.int(100);
    var b = _.int(200);
    var c = _.int(300);
    _.return(_.['+'](a, _['+'](b, c)));
});

console.log(main.compile());
```

Internally `jsc` would generate something like this:

```
var fs = new FunctionScope();

var a = new Object(Type.int(), 100);
var b = new Object(Type.int(), 200);
var c = new Object(Type.int(), 300);
fs.body.push(new Declaration(a));
fs.body.push(new Declaration(b));
fs.body.push(new Declaration(c));

var pa = new PrimaryExpression(a);
var pb = new PrimaryExpression(b);
var pc = new PrimaryExpression(c);
var expr1 = new AdditionExpression(pb, pc);
var expr2 = new AdditionExpression(pa, expr1);
fs.body.push(new ReturnStatement(expr2));

var codegen = new Codegen();
var bin = codegen.compileFunction(fs);
console.log(bin);
```

Comment: every lvalue is an expression, not every expression is an lvalue

Comment: Are you sure you want to use your precious time to make yet another C compiler? That stuff is quite hard to get right.

Comment: @RyanHaining Let's say `var a = 1; a++;` In `a++;` *expression-statement*, in `a++` *expression*, the `a` variable is what? *expression*? *lvalue*? *object*?

Comment: @BaummitAugen There are no C compilers in JavaScript.

Comment: @Vad That's mainly because no one needs a C compiler in JavaScript.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Well I need one, so how can you say that no one needs one.

Comment: @Vad Eh, I doubt that. Looks more like an XY-problem. I'm rather confident because no one would do that in real life and it's to big for an assignment,

Comment: @BaummitAugen No, it's definitely not XY-problem, and I'm doing it in real life and its actually not that hard, the hard part obviously is to optimize the machine code which is a separate problem.

Comment: @Vad Alright. Gl hf.

Comment: @BaummitAugen gl hf

Comment: @Vad , as far as a compiler goes, I don't think there is such a thing as `object`. Everything is `rvalue`, `lvalue`, `expression` **and** / **or** `type` (`type` can be `struct` which has it's own namespace but is still a struct) within a `scope` (`scope` can be `global`, which is still a scope)... but I might be wrong, I never wrote a compiler.

Comment: The JISON lexer/parser (https://github.com/zaach/jison Bison compatibel to a great extend) has an ANSI-C grammar (and lexer) as an example. Do you use that?

Comment: "its actually not that hard" - Your question tells something different ...

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I actually don't have a parser, I start from an AST, though I will have convenience methods to easily build AST in JavaScript, it will be like writing C in JavaScript, of course, you can easily add a parser as a frontent later.

Comment: @Myst see [this on objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object)

Comment: @Olaf Do you know the answer? What is `a`?

Comment: @Vad , `object`, much like `pointer`, is a type of expression. I'm not saying that they do not exist in C, I'm just saying that they are a child class, similarly to how `pointer` is a type of `object`. For that matter, `lvalue` and `rvalue` are probably state specifiers inside an `expression` rather then a class.

Comment: @Myst thank you, so what would be the base class from which `pointer` and `expression` inherit?

Comment: @Myst: The C standard does not support classes, nor does it use that term. The term "object" in C is well defined. It does not have the same meaning like in OOP! They are **not** "a type of expression"!

Comment: @Vad: If you want to create an implementation for C, you have to read **and understand** the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). That exactly defines the terms. Asking particular questions here is near useless.

Comment: @Olaf I've read the C99 standard, it mostly deals with parsing though, which I don't need at all. I start from AST, thus I am more interested in the relationships between the resulting structures.

Comment: @Vad: C99 is **not** C standard since ca. 5 years now! Anyway: 1) you don't need aprsing for a compiler? Strange attitude! 2) It does **not** "mostly deal with parsing". If you really think it does, you did not read/understand it! Most part discusses the library, but the rest is **mostly** about semantics! That's exactly what you are asking about. 3) Implemention a compiler without reading&understanding the specification is doomed from the start.

Comment: "expression evaluates to lvalue" is sloppy language, it means "lvalue expression evaluates to designator of a memory location"

Comment: @Myst check the C standard, there certainly is "object"

Comment: @M.M: Slight correction: 6.3.2.1p1 - "An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that **potentially** designates an **object**. ..." - Not necessarily and not just an arbitrary memory location, but an object.

Comment: @Olaf , @M.M , with all due respect, the OP's question related to the use of classes in an OO design for a C compiler. All I state is that `object` is an unnecessary class. Your references in this regard are somewhat besides the point.

Comment: @Olaf evaluating an lvalue that doesn't actually designate an object is undefined behaviour, so we can ignore that case

Comment: @Myst: OP apparently refers to some C reference (of suspicious origin&quality). So it is not clear if he means the C terms or that of his - also unspecified - OOP language.

Comment: @Olaf "C99 is not C standard since ca. 5 years now!", how does it matter in this discussion? "you don't need aprsing for a compiler?" as I wrote I start from AST so I don't need parsing, that's one of the reasons for the original question to better understand the relationships between different parts. "Implemention a compiler without reading&understanding the specification is doomed from the start.", as I said I read the standard and believe it or not I understand it too, don't think I'm doomed, I'll be just fine; the question was though how to model the structure OO way.

Comment: @M.M: It is UB, but the expression is not always evaluated, e.g. for `sizeof`?

Comment: yes, `sizeof` cases are also not relevant to discussion of evaluating an lvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I need to understand is what is the exact relationship between types, values, expressions and objects

Expressions have a type and e*valuate* to values. Objects contain data that, when interpreted as a specific type, may represent values (*may* because an object can be uninitialized or otherwise contain invalid data). Lvalues (which are a type of expression) refer to objects. To quote the relevant definitions from the standard:

> **3.15**
>
> **object**
>
> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values
>
> **3.19**
>
> **value**
>
> precise meaning of the contents of an object when interpreted as having a specific type
>
> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
>
> An lvalue is  an  expression  (with  an  object  type  other  than `void`)  that  potentially designates an object

---

> `a++;` is expression-statement, right?

Yes, an expression statement is an expression followed by a semicolon (grammar rule: "*expression_statement*: *expression*<sub>opt</sub> **;**" from section 6.8.3 of the standard). `a++` is an expression thus `a++;` is an expression statement.

> `a++` is expression, with postfix increment operator, right?

Right. The relevant clauses of the grammar are "*postfix-expression*: *postfix-expression* **++**", "*postfix-expression*: *primary-expression*" (section 6.5.2) and "*primary-expression*: *identifier*" (section 6.5.1). So we get the following derivation (skipping part of the expression hierarchy for brevity) for `a++;`:

```
     expression-statement
   expression           ';'
   postfix-expression   ';'
postfix-expression '++' ';'
primary-expression '++' ';'
identifier         '++' ';'
'a'                '++' ';'
```

> `a`, so what is `a`? Is it expression, object, or lvalue? Or is `a` an expression that evaluates to lvalue and this lvalue has an associated object and type?

Syntactically `a` is an identifier, which is a primary expression, which is an expression. Semantically it's the name of a variable and a variable is an object. As cited above, "an lvalue is  an  expression  (with  an  object  type  other  than `void`)  that  potentially designates an object" (section 6.3.2.1), so `a` is also an `lvalue`.

Comment: Values have a type, expressions yield values. You answer could have been a comment linking to the C standard (might have been the easier and more helpful way)

Comment: @Olaf Expressions have types, which determine how a given object is interpreted as a value (from 6.2.5. Values: "The meaning of a value stored in an object or returned by a function is determined by the
**type of  the  expression**  used  to  access  it."). And yes, I could've just posted a link to the standard, which certainly would've been less effort, but a) I don't see how summarizing and quoting the relevant sections is *less* helpful than ... not doing that and b) questions shouldn't be answered in comments as then the question will keep appearing as an unanswered question.

Comment: Hmm, that is true for lvalues. Non-lvalue expression just yield a value and values have types. Major point is the question itself is far too broad. The standard shall be read&understood anyway and the design of the compiler is a matter of opinion. I didn't say the question shall be answered in a comment, but there is no acceptable answer within site rules.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that "expressions evaluate to values". If the expression is an lvalue then it does not evaluate to a value.  The process of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is separate to evaluation, and happens in some contexts only.

Comment: So what do you think about the following OO design? I will have a base `Expression` class from which all different *expressions* will inherit. The `Expression` class will have an `.evaluate()` method that will return an instance of `Value`. `Value` will be a base class from which all values (*lvalue*, *rvalue* and *function designator*) will inherit. And `Object` will be yet another class that can be referenced by `LValue` class instances. Should something like that work or am I missing shomething?

Comment: @Vad I thought you were writing a compiler. Barring optimizations such as constant folding, a compiler doesn't evaluate anything (and thus doesn't need an `evaluate` method). Evaluation happens when the generated code is executed.

Comment: @sepp2k ok, I'm probably naming the `.evaluate()` method incorrectly, I should probably call it `.getValue()`

Comment: @Vad It doesn't matter what you name it. If what it does is to take an expression and produce a value, that's not supposed to happen during compilation. There is no reason for a `Value` class to even exist in a compiler outside of the optimizer.